# How to copy a sql file from one server another server mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, ssh

I tried copy a sql file from one server another server mysql database

```
ssh -i keylocation user@host 'mysql --user=root --password="pass" --host=ipaddress additional_content Additional_Content' | < databasedump.sql
```

databasedump.sql - file on server A, I wanna copy data from that database file into database on server B, i tried to connec via ssh,  to that server,and i need keyfile for that, and then copy the data, but when i run this command into console, nothing happens, any help?

Comment: scp or a tunnel could help, but your question is most likely off topic

Comment: scp will copy the file into another server, but i wanna copy the data from sqlfile into database on another server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to secure copy the file over to server B first, and then ssh in for the mysql dump? Example:

`scp databasedump.sql user@server-B:/path/to/databasedump.sql`

`ssh -i keylocation user@host 'mysql --user=root --password="pass" --database=db_name < /path/to/databasedump.sql'`

Edit: type-o

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure how mysql handles stdin, so one thing you can do that should work in one command is

```
ssh -i keylocation user@host 'cat - | mysql --user=root --password="pass" --host=ipaddress additional_content Additional_Content' < databasedump.sql
```

However it's better to copy the files first with `scp`, and then import it with mysql. See Dan's answer.